# Doesn't fire when using .on?

Tags: jquery

What I expect here is the function to fire when I click the class, but it doesn't happen! The a.button is dynamically created but IS on the page when it's fully loaded!

Any ideas why?

HTML:

```
   <a class="btn btn-success useImg">
          <i class="fa-icon-plus"></i>
          <span>Use</span>
   </a>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(".useImg").on("click", function(){
    alert("test");
    });
```

Comment: Try if delegation helps anyways. `$(document).on("click", ".useImg", ...)`

Comment: Did you forget to wrap in `$(document).ready(...)`, perhaps?

Comment: And what version of jQuery are you using? `on()` was added in 1.7 (prior to that `delegate()` is recommended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the click event to another element further up the DOM tree and then filter it to work on your anchor element. That will fire for any elements with the `.useImg` class including those added dynamically.

```
$('body').on("click", ".useImg", function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Make sure you wrap the code in the jQuery DOM Ready event to ensure the page has fully loaded. eg

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on("click", ".useImg", function(){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: Given the element is (supposedly) present on page load, how can this help?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Tried .live aswell which made it, but your ideas was better. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kim don't use `live`. It's long deprecated and removed from 1.9

Comment: When you're binding to `body`, there's no reason to wait for the DOM ready

Comment: also, I'm not happy about that `'body'`. `document.body` is much faster (and cooler), and `document` is a viable binding target, too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Your code works perfectly fine in a standalone jsFiddle which you can see [here](http://bit.ly/13qYyIS).

Therefore, you must have one of these issues:

1. You are trying to install the event handler before the DOM is ready or before the object exists.
2. You have an error in your javascript that prevents the event handler from being installed.
3. The actual code in your page or HTML is not the same as what you put in the question so there's some other issue that isn't disclosed.

You can protect against the first item by either putting your code in a `$(document).ready()` handler or by using delegated event handling.

For the second item, you have to check your browser error console for script errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try, when document is ready

```
$(function() {
 $(".useImg").on("click", function(){
    alert("test");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(
  $('.useImg').click(function(){ alert(test); })
)
```

Comment: Ahh.. I forgot to write $(document).ready().. editing the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("body").on("click", ".useImg", function(){
    alert("test");
    });`

and it is recommended that you use latest jquery lib 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js